# What is network weight and my weight?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, casper

What does it mean by my weight and the network weight in POS ?

-Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link where you saw those terms?

Comment: I saw in some POS coin wallet which was minting

Comment: you mean it's not Ethereum related? Dangerous thing here in the StEx ;-)

Comment: when ether would start to go POS, then it will be, wouldn't it ?

Comment: It depends how the PoS is implemented. It's possible Ethereum's PoS would be implemented completely differently to whatever system you were looking at. _"I saw in some POS coin wallet which was minting"_ - what wallet, and what network?

Answer (score 2):

The [Whitepaper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) - in its [History](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#history) section - explains that in the current Proof of Work system:

> ...the weight of a single node in the consensus voting process is
>   directly proportional to the computing power that the node brings.

In which case, the "network weight" would be the total hashing power of the network.

---

It then goes on to explain the same for the proposed Proof of Stake consensus mechanism:

> ...an alternative approach has been proposed called proof of stake,
>   calculating the weight of a node as being proportional to its currency
>   holdings and not its computational resources.

Again, in this case we can extrapolate the meaning of "network weight" to be the combined total currency held by all bonded validator nodes.